# Self Intersection of a Fiber

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, intersection-theory

I have a question about an argument in the proof Prop. 2.3 in Hartshorne's "Algebraic Geometry" (chapter V, page 370/371):

[image]

That's not clear to me why the self intersection of the (closed) fiber $f^2$ should be vanish. What is meant here by ***two*** distinct fibers? Honestly, it's not clear how this argument works.

Remark: $f= \pi^{-1}(b)$ for a closed $b$.

According to page 358 the self intersection can be calculated via $f^2 = deg(\mathcal{L}(f) \vert _f)$ where $\mathcal{L}(f)$ is of course the invertible sheaf corresponding to $f$ interpreted as Cartier divisor.

Answer (score 1):

$X$ is a $\Bbb P^1$-bundle over $C$, and for $b\ne c\in C$, $\pi^{-1}(b)\cap \pi^{-1}(c) = \emptyset$, just by set theory. (Note that any two fibers are homologous — or numerically equivalent.)

Comment: Yes, yes, that's already clear. But how does it contribute to the argument that $f^2=0$?

Comment: Because the intersection number is the number of points (counted with appropriate scheme structure) in the set-theoretic intersection.

Comment: ...if the two schemes don't have common irreducible components, right? But here we consider a self intersection of $f$, so I don't understand why we here consider two different fibers.

Comment: Because they're homologous. Another way to think about it is that the normal bundle of a fiber is trivial and you're computing the self-intersection of the zero-section of the normal bundle. (Note that for an exceptional divisor in a surface, the normal bundle is negative and there is no holomorphic section other than the zero section.)

Comment: Have you a hint how to see that two fibers are numerically equivalent? (by the way: Are they maybe also linearly equivalent? If yes, why?)

Comment: Topologically, if you take an arc $\sigma$ in $C$ joining $b$ and $c$, then $\pi^{-1}(\sigma)$ gives a $3$-chain whose boundary is the $2$-cycle $\pi^{-1}(c)-\pi^{-1}(b)$. A fiber and a nearby fiber are certainly algebraically equivalent (using projection to $C$).  You can get linear equivalence, I guess, if you choose a branched covering $p\colon C\to\Bbb P^1$, not branched at $b$, and let $f=p\circ\pi$.

Comment: @TedShifrin, how do you know that all curves numerically equivalent to the fiber $f$ is a fiber as well? Given that, I agree $f^2=0$ is immediate

Comment: @rmdmc89: That is a converse that is surely false. Why do you want that?

Comment: @TedShifrin, in order to prove $f^2= 0$ we must prove that for every $g$ equivalent to $f$ we have $f\cap g= \emptyset$, right? But the textbook only argues that the _fibers_ are disjoint (which is an obvious statement), but what if $g$ is not a fiber?

Comment: @rmdmc89 No, you only need to find *one* representative of the equivalence class that is disjoint. This is the point of working with homology (or linear/rational equivalence).

Comment: @TedShifrin oh, I see. I get it now, thank you